# Compiler flag to include some_file_name.h into all files?

Tags: c++

I am working on my honors thesis and want to change my threading method from std::threads to include boost::threadpool. I am able to accomplish this easily by just doing a

```
#include "../include/threadpool.hpp"
```

within each of my files, but this becomes very repetitive with many files / changes to thread systems. Is there some way to give a compiler flag (or something else) so that all files natively #include that file?

My naive thought would be something like

```
//dependencies.h
#include "../include/threadpool.hpp"
#include //some other dependency I need.h
```

And pass a
-I "path_to_dependencies.h"
 flag to compiler. Would something like this work or am I off base?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is the preferred way to do it. In fact you can go one step farther and make it a precompiled header, which will cut down compilation time by a *lot*, especially if your project gets large.

I assume you're using gcc, you can read about precompiled headers here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html

For Microsoft's compiler you have the `stdafx.h` file everyone knows about since it enables precompiled headers by default.

Comment: So just put all of my required headers into one header, #include that header into all of my required files?  
I could see this leading to circular #includes pretty easily, any suggestions to avoid this?

Comment: Circular includes don't matter if you write the properly. `#pragma once` alone avoids most problems, and the rest you can avoid yourself.